# Will my job have a negative impact on my profile as a graduate student applicant?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, masters, career-path, education

I am a senior undergraduate in Electrical and Electronics Engineering, and I ultimately want to pursue a Master's degree in the field of Embedded Systems. However, my current financial situation prohibits me from paying for this, so I have decided to take a couple years off in order to save money and to apply for loans and scholarships. To that end, I have recently accepted a job in the IT department of a respected bank (I was unable to find a job in the field of Embedded Systems). Since I am not able to work in my target domain, will this time off negatively affect my prospects at top graduate programs?

Comment: Your question is very localized, but there's a useful nugget in the form of "will an industry job hinder/help my future plans for graduate school". Maybe you'd consider an edit to focus on the general question ?

Comment: Unfortunately, probably yes. How much so will depend on graduate programs' perception of how difficult it is for undergraduates to find industry jobs. (If is common for very good students to fail to find jobs in your specialty and region of the world, then professors are likely to know about it and not hold this much against you.) However, this is certainly not fatal to your chances. Best of luck to you!

Comment: _my current financial situation prohibits me from paying for this_ — I assume you mean "but my current financial situation makes it impossible to live on a graduate student stipend."

Comment: @JeffE I am sorry but I don't know of any graduate student stipend. I am an Indian student aiming for graduate schools in the US

Comment: If a graduate school in the US is not willing to offer you an assistantship that pays you a stipend, Do. Not. Go.

Comment: @JeffE as an applicant for next season, I thought this applied more to phd programs than ms programs?

Comment: @JeffE Why do say that? I have come to know that assistantships are hard to come by. Some of my friends joining this fall don't have TA or RA offers.

Comment: PhD programs always offer stipends to the students they value.  Contrarily, Masters programs (even at the same schools) usually don't, assistantships give priority to PhD students, and Masters tuition can be pretty pricey on top of that.  Especially for foreign students, the exchange rate can make tuition and living in the US quite difficult financially.

Answer (score 3):

Masters degrees are often funded not by the university but by an employer.  Generally with the requirement that you continue working during your program, which constrains choice of school geographically (has to be close to the employer), the rate at which you complete a program (part-time, not full load), and only works for the degree most closely associated with the job you do -- companies don't fund you to move on to bigger and better things elsewhere, they invest in making their employees provide more value back to them.

Your job history shouldn't have a lot of impact other than whether it enables you to be employer-funded, and in the case described of working in your field but outside your desired specialization, it pretty much rules out receiving that benefit.

On the other hand, most Masters (MS, MSE, or MEng) in Engineering programs even at highly ranked schools don't have extremely competitive admissions.  So you might focus on trying to find employment (and the necessary visas) compatible with the program you want to enter.

Comment: Actually I am aiming at the MS program not the M.Eng program. I am not quite sure about the MEng progam. I believe the MS program has a more rigorous curriculum. It is more technical and less managerial.
Also as far as I know, visa is not granted fro people looking jobs abroad but only for education.

Comment: @user191156: I didn't mean that the curriculum isn't rigorous, or is less technical.  But when there's no money being given out along with admission, admissions aren't as selective.  Work visas are definitely harder to get than academic visas.  Which is why I said focus on obtaining a work visa and job, if you pull that off you won't have to worry about whether you will be allowed to enroll.